# Stripe. Monthly subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to implement a monthly subscription with Stripe and PHP. I followed that instructions: https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/subscription-signup#creating-the-signup-form-using-checkout

1- I have gone to the Dashboard and created a product: Monthtly fee and a plan of 9.99 eur/month with the name Monthly1. Let's say that the id of the product is prod_222222w

2- Index.php:

```
<form action="create_subscription.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_SomeNumbersAndLetters"
    data-image="images/stripe.png"
    data-name="F. subscription"
    data-description="9.99 montly fee"
    data-amount="999"
    data-label="Sign Me Up!">
  </script>
</form>
```

3-create_subscription.php. I installed Composer and I think, it works well

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_SomeNumbersAndLetters");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  ));

  $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'items' => array(array('plan' => 'weekly_box')),
  ));

  header('Location: thankyou.php');
  exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  header('Location:oops.php');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

If I understand I have to change the id of the plan. Where should I put that?
If I understand I have to change also the stripeToken and stripeEmail. If so, where I get that and where I have to put it?

Sorry, I am very confused. I am not a programmer. I teach myself. I managed to build a site, but implementing Stripe is the most difficult part. I would appreciate any orientation.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"If I understand I have to change the id of the plan. Where should I put that?"* - from looking at the code, I assume you need to provide the plan ID here:

```
'items' => array(array('plan' => 'PLAN_ID_HERE'))...
```

*"If I understand I have to change also the stripeToken and stripeEmail"* - you do not need to change these, leave them as `$_POST['stripeEmail']` and `$_POST['stripeToken']` and these parameters will be pulled in from the Checkout application.

Be sure to use the proper 'test' data/API keys for testing, and then replace them with the correct 'live' data/API keys once you are ready to make it live.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. If I test this code with the test numbers—4242 4242 4242 4242 It seems to work, I get the green icon after I hit the pay button, but then it drives me to the error page: oops.php. On the other side I get the succeed in Dashboard > Payments

Comment: If I use the wrong numbers provided in the tutorial I also get the green icon and drives me to the oops.php page. In this case, nothings happens in the Dashboard.

Comment: Do you have access to the error log? If not, could you replace the code in the catch `{ }` to the following: `echo "unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'] .", error:" . $e->getMessage());` and tell me what the script prints?

Comment: No, sorry. I deleted my previous comment because  I realized I had changed a thing in my code when I tried things. If I put the code I provide here in Stackoverflow php_error.log says: unable to sign up customer: nr@myMail.com, error:No such plan: weekly_box . If I change that and I put the name of the plan that I have in Dashboard > Billing > Products > Pricing plans The error says "not such plan"

Comment: Is there a test plan name you should be using instead?

Comment: I used the name  in the Dashboard Pricing plans when I have activated the "Viewing test data" I do not see any other option in the documentation.

Comment: Have you entered the proper test API key here: `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("YOUR_TEST_API_KEY");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182602/discussion-between-nrc-and-justin-t).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I give the complete solution here if someone else got that problem. The answer of Justin T is correct. You only have to change the plan ID. To get that, you have to go to Stripe > Dashboard > Billing > Products > Pricing plans and click on the name of your Pricing Plan.